# How to write an excel sheet per directory wise for a list of directory inside a directory using Python

Tags: python, excel

I have a list of directories inside a directory. I'm currently preparing a report for each directory which I need to write it as an excel sheet.

The problem I'm observing is the excel sheet is not getting saved for each particular directory. Only the last directory saves it.

Here's the code :

```
for item in iter(dir_list):
                xl_name = item +'.xlsx'

            workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(xl_name)
            bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': 1})
            row = 1
            col = 0
            while i < len(t['values']):
                my_new_string = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9 \n\.]', '', t1[i]['displayId'])

                worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(str(my_new_string[:30]))
                worksheet.write('A1', 'xxxxx', bold)
                * Some Parsing *
                ************
                for line in count.split('\n'):
                   worksheet.write_string(row, col, str((line.split(";;;"))[0].split(";")[0]))
                   row += 1
                   i = i + 1
```

I am using xlsx writer to achieve this. I can use another module also. Can you please help me understanding where i am going wrong.

Comment: I miss a `workbook.close()` call in your code (at the end of your `item` iteration loop)

Comment: Yes i have added that but i am observing this error :     workbook.close()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 310, in close
    self._store_workbook()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 37: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: workbook.close() error i am able to fix and can see excel is getting created. But i have introduced another problem the worksheets which should be multiple from here :worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(str(my_new_string[:30])) , i can only see first sheet being created.

Comment: Fix your indentation. Your final `i = i + 1` is indented one level too deep.

Comment: I am able to get the solution. Thank You for your kind help @jbndlr .